# Keras intermediate layer (attention model) output

Tags: python, keras, numpy

I have a model with this summary:

---

```
___________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 30, 37)        0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
s0 (InputLayer)                  (None, 128)           0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirectional)  (None, 30, 128)       52224       input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_1 (RepeatVector)   (None, 30, 128)       0           s0[0][0]                         
                                                                   lstm_1[0][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[1][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[2][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[3][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[4][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[5][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[6][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[7][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[8][0]                     
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)      (None, 30, 256)       0           bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   repeat_vector_1[0][0]            
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   repeat_vector_1[1][0]            
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   repeat_vector_1[2][0]            
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   repeat_vector_1[3][0]            
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   repeat_vector_1[4][0]            
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   repeat_vector_1[5][0]            
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   repeat_vector_1[6][0]            
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   repeat_vector_1[7][0]            
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   repeat_vector_1[8][0]            
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   repeat_vector_1[9][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 30, 1)         257         concatenate_1[0][0]              
                                                                   concatenate_1[1][0]              
                                                                   concatenate_1[2][0]              
                                                                   concatenate_1[3][0]              
                                                                   concatenate_1[4][0]              
                                                                   concatenate_1[5][0]              
                                                                   concatenate_1[6][0]              
                                                                   concatenate_1[7][0]              
                                                                   concatenate_1[8][0]              
                                                                   concatenate_1[9][0]              
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
attention_weights (Activation)   (None, 30, 1)         0           dense_1[0][0]                    
                                                                   dense_1[1][0]                    
                                                                   dense_1[2][0]                    
                                                                   dense_1[3][0]                    
                                                                   dense_1[4][0]                    
                                                                   dense_1[5][0]                    
                                                                   dense_1[6][0]                    
                                                                   dense_1[7][0]                    
                                                                   dense_1[8][0]                    
                                                                   dense_1[9][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dot_1 (Dot)                      (None, 1, 128)        0           attention_weights[0][0]          
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   attention_weights[1][0]          
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   attention_weights[2][0]          
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   attention_weights[3][0]          
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   attention_weights[4][0]          
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   attention_weights[5][0]          
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   attention_weights[6][0]          
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   attention_weights[7][0]          
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   attention_weights[8][0]          
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   attention_weights[9][0]          
                                                                   bidirectional_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
c0 (InputLayer)                  (None, 128)           0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                    [(None, 128), (None,  131584      dot_1[0][0]                      
                                                                   s0[0][0]                         
                                                                   c0[0][0]                         
                                                                   dot_1[1][0]                      
                                                                   lstm_1[0][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[0][2]                     
                                                                   dot_1[2][0]                      
                                                                   lstm_1[1][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[1][2]                     
                                                                   dot_1[3][0]                      
                                                                   lstm_1[2][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[2][2]                     
                                                                   dot_1[4][0]                      
                                                                   lstm_1[3][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[3][2]                     
                                                                   dot_1[5][0]                      
                                                                   lstm_1[4][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[4][2]                     
                                                                   dot_1[6][0]                      
                                                                   lstm_1[5][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[5][2]                     
                                                                   dot_1[7][0]                      
                                                                   lstm_1[6][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[6][2]                     
                                                                   dot_1[8][0]                      
                                                                   lstm_1[7][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[7][2]                     
                                                                   dot_1[9][0]                      
                                                                   lstm_1[8][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[8][2]                     
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 11)            1419        lstm_1[0][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[1][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[2][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[3][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[4][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[5][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[6][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[7][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[8][0]                     
                                                                   lstm_1[9][0]                     
====================================================================================================
Total params: 185,484
Trainable params: 185,484
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The model is further summarised as:

[image]

And the "attention" block summarised as:

[image]

The input is a fuzzy date, e.g. "November 17, 1979" (capped at 30 characters) and the output is the 10 character representation "YYYY-mm-dd".

**I would like to plot the values of the `attention_weights` layer.**

I would like to see which part of "Saturday, 17th November, 1979" the network "looks at" when it predicts each of `YYYY`, `mm`, and `dd`. I'm expecting to see it ignores the day ("Saturday") completely.

I've tried following the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/) for obtaining the output of an intermediate layer.

However, the attention node has 10 inputs, so I have to grab each of those:

```
f = K.function(model.inputs, [model.get_layer('attention_weights').get_output_at(t) for t in range(10)])
r = f([source, np.zeros((1,128)), np.zeros((1,128))])
```

With `source` e.g. "17 November 1979" encoded as

```
[[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
    1.]]]
```

`r` is then a matrix of shape `(10,1,30,1)` and the attention map I'm plotting it thus:

```
attention_map = np.zeros((10, 30))
for t in range(10):
    for t_prime in range(30):
        attention_map[t][t_prime] = r[t][0,t_prime,0]
```

**...but all the values are the same! I'm expecting *some* variation.**

I've also tried adding `K.learning_phase()` to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I tried to plot the attention map of a model which was loaded from a saved model.

The output when the model was saved was:

> /home/opyate/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py:2361:
>   UserWarning: Layer lstm_1 was passed non-serializable keyword
>   arguments: {'initial_state': [, ]}.
>   They will not be included in the serialized model (and thus will be
>   missing at deserialization time).   str(node.arguments) + '. They will
>   not be included '
>   /home/opyate/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py:2361:
>   UserWarning: Layer lstm_1 was passed non-serializable keyword
>   arguments: {'initial_state': [, ]}. They will not be included in the
>   serialized model (and thus will be missing at deserialization time).
>   str(node.arguments) + '. They will not be included '
>   /home/opyate/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py:2361:
>   UserWarning: Layer lstm_1 was passed non-serializable keyword
>   arguments: {'initial_state': [,
>   ]}.
>   They will not be included in the serialized model (and thus will be
>   missing at deserialization time).   str(node.arguments) + '. They will
>   not be included '
>   /home/opyate/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py:2361:
>   UserWarning: Layer lstm_1 was passed non-serializable keyword
>   arguments: {'initial_state': [,
>   ]}.
>   They will not be included in the serialized model (and thus will be
>   missing at deserialization time).   str(node.arguments) + '. They will
>   not be included '
>   /home/opyate/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py:2361:
>   UserWarning: Layer lstm_1 was passed non-serializable keyword
>   arguments: {'initial_state': [,
>   ]}.
>   They will not be included in the serialized model (and thus will be
>   missing at deserialization time).   str(node.arguments) + '. They will
>   not be included '
>   /home/opyate/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py:2361:
>   UserWarning: Layer lstm_1 was passed non-serializable keyword
>   arguments: {'initial_state': [,
>   ]}.
>   They will not be included in the serialized model (and thus will be
>   missing at deserialization time).   str(node.arguments) + '. They will
>   not be included '
>   /home/opyate/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py:2361:
>   UserWarning: Layer lstm_1 was passed non-serializable keyword
>   arguments: {'initial_state': [,
>   ]}.
>   They will not be included in the serialized model (and thus will be
>   missing at deserialization time).   str(node.arguments) + '. They will
>   not be included '
>   /home/opyate/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py:2361:
>   UserWarning: Layer lstm_1 was passed non-serializable keyword
>   arguments: {'initial_state': [,
>   ]}.
>   They will not be included in the serialized model (and thus will be
>   missing at deserialization time).   str(node.arguments) + '. They will
>   not be included '

However, if I construct the model from code, and just load the saved weights, it works.

The assumption is that the `UserWarning`s when saving the model has something to do with my problem.